# some of data is been takin from _Posts but one of them i want a static text

Tags: php, codeigniter

on my **controller Code**

```
                       $data=array(
                        'username'=>$_POST['username'],
                        'password'=>sha1($_POST['password']),
                        'email'=>$_POST['email'],
                        'user_type'=>"user"
                    );
```

here o the (user_type) I want to add text like (user) this must insert static
this controller is new it's works if I get it from post but I want static

regards

Comment: make sure the datatype of the user_type field matches that of the value you want to save in it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its static, then you probably don't need to pass it in the array.  Seems like the array is passing 'variables'. Static data is not technically variable by it's very description of 'static'.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$data=array(
  'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
  'password'=>sha1($this->input->post('password')),
  'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
  'user_type'=>'user'
);
```

Comment: it's not working it insert other< username, password,email> where it get from form but the user_type says can't be null as I set not null is required from this data array it's seem not getting it